# Equicontinuous function on $[0,T]$ with values in $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces, equicontinuity

Let $\{u_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\subset C([0,T];\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n))$ be a family of continuous maps from $[0,T]$ to $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Suppose that $\{u_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ is equicontinuous on $[0,T]$, and that $\{u_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ is uniformly bounded. Can we conclude that there exists a subsequence $u_n \to w\in C([0,T];\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n))$?

This seems straightforward if we replace $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by some metric space and then it's just the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem. Is there a counterpart of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem for general topological space?

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the topology on $C([0,T];\mathcal S '(\mathbb R^{n}))$? And what do equi- continuity and uniform boundedness mean?

Comment: The natural topology to use on $V=C([0,T],\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n))$ I think should be the locally convex one defined by the seminorms $||f||=\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\rho(f(t))$ where $\rho$ is a continuous seminorm for the strong topology of $\mathscr{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Equivalently, one can use $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\sup_{u\in A}|f(t)(u)|$ where $A$ is a bounded subset of Schwartz space. This is a good question and I suspect, with the right definitions, the answer should be positive.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I feel like the boundedness should be defined by strong topology to ensure pointwise compactness of the family of continuous maps in weak topology. And I think the convergence should be true by some general version of Ascoli theorem in uniform space with weak topology on $\mathcal{S}′(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (I find a statement in Stephen Willard's $\textit{General Topology}$. But I'm not familiar with this general version.)

Comment: I would stay away from weak topology.

Comment: An instructive case to start with is $T=0$. There the Montel property of $S'$ should play a role (the only one) in your question. Also, you can make your question more tractable by replacing Schwartz space and its dual by the space of rapidly decaying sequences and its dual. They are isomorphic.